# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a simple web scraping program written in `Python` which is meant to find the method for a recipe however, I get this error message when I run the code:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

quote_page = 'http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/easy-pan-roasted-chicken-and-shallots.html'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'name'})
name = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
print name
```

Comment: Evidently `name_box is None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

There is no `p` element with `class="name"` on the page, which means that `name_box` is `None`.

> meant to find the *method for a recipe*

For the recipe method, you can use the `recipeInstructions` itemprop attribute value:

```
instructions = soup.find("div", itemprop="recipeInstructions")
print(instructions.get_text(strip=True))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> 
>>> quote_page = 'http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/easy-pan-roasted-chicken-and-shallots.html'
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
>>> 
>>> instructions = soup.find("div", itemprop="recipeInstructions")
>>> print(instructions.get_text(strip=True))
Preheat the oven to 220°C. Sprinkle both sides of the chicken breasts with salt and pepper.Preheat a large, oven-safe frying pan over medium-high heat for 2 minutes. Working quickly, melt 1 tablespoon of the butter, swirling it around the pan. Add the chicken, skin side down. Add the shallots, cut side down and not overlapping. Cook until the chicken and shallots are browned on the bottom, 2 to 3 minutes. Flip the shallots and chicken, nestle in the rosemary sprigs, then carefully pour in the chicken stock.Transfer the frying pan to the oven and roast until the chicken is cooked through and the shallots are tender, 12 to 14 minutes, removing the smaller pieces of chicken first as they become cooked. Transfer the chicken to a serving plate.Check the frying pan with the shallots to make sure the stock has not evaporated; if less than a few tablespoons remain, add 1/2 cup more stock or water.  Reduce the pan juices over medium heat until about 1/2 cup of liquid remains, about 2 minutes. Remove the frying pan from the heat and stir in the remaining 2 tablespoons of butter with a wooden spoon to thicken the pan sauce until it coats the spoon. Remove the rosemary and season the sauce with salt and pepper. Spoon some of the sauce over the chicken and shallots and the rest onto the plate.Copyright 2014 Television Food Network, G.P. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to extract the `text` content from the `HTTP` response and parse that

use `.read()`

```
quote_page = 'http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/easy-pan-roasted-chicken-and-shallots.html'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup would call `.read()` implicitly. [It is supported](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup).

Comment: Never knew that.Thanks