# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' bBeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x

flipkartProductPrice =float(flipkartSoup.find('div',attrs='_30jeq3 _16Jk6d').text.replace(',','')[1:])
amazonProductPrice = float(amazonSoup.find('span', attrs='priceblock_ourppriceBlockBuyingPriceString').text.replace(',','')[1:])

so this was my code & after getting 2 URLs it worked like
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123271/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-python-2-7)

Comment: please paste your code inside ``` .  for example: ``` print("hello") ```